# How do I populate a form in JSP with data obtained from a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a working Javascript function `manipulateData()` in a some.js file.

I have included that JS file in info.jsp in head and also made it available on body load. Within `manipulateData()` function, I have another function which returns that data which I want to use to populate that JSP form.

How can I invoke the function within a JS function from the JS file, in a JSP. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking in the sentence "So my problem is as to how can I invoke the function within a JS function from the JS file, in a JSP"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but ...

An inner function will only ever exist if its outer function is executed, and each execution of the outer function will create a fresh instance of that inner function.

An inner functions will cease to exist when the outer function completes unless a persistent reference to the inner function is kept, either :

- by assignment to a js var (or object property) in the outer function's outer scope (eg by having the outer function return the inner function), or
- by attachment to a DOM element as an event handler.